# Trouble formatting code to meet my conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to re-work this code I found to combine and sum rows in a sheet.

I have a sheet with values in columns columns A-G. And a Dynamic number of rows.

If an exact duplicate is found in column D, I want to add (sum) the "column G" and "column H" values from the duplicate row, with the "G" and "H" values from the original row. With the result being in the original row.

For all other columns, I want the duplicate row to overwrite the original. (Or, overwrite if the exact same, and place next to the original value in the same cell if different, but this is beyond my knowledge.)

To clarify, the code will loop through column 'D' until it finds duplicate values. It will then delete the row of this duplicate value, after copying/pasting its values over those of the original. Except for "G" and "H", where it will sum its values with the original rows "G" and "h".

ie.

| June 1 | A | ----- | **1234** | Walmart | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| June 2 | B | BA | **1234** | Walmart | 4 | 4 |

Would turn into

| June 2 | B | BA | **1234** | Walmart | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

In place of the original, for all duplicate (column "D") rows in the worksheet.

Thanks for any input.

This code I've been trying to change: works for 4 columns where column A is the ID as opposed to column D, and doesn't include the sum condition. I'm having trouble fitting it to my conditions. Specifically, why is the Cl range 'B' when this range isn't consequential, and what format the offset follows.

```
Sub mergeRows()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.Comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Dim Cl As Range, x$, y$, i&, Key As Variant
    For Each Cl In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        x = Cl.Value & "|" & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
        y = Cl.Offset(, 2).Value
        If Not Dic.exists(x) Then
            Dic.Add x, Cl.Offset(, -1).Value & "|" & y & "|"
        ElseIf Dic.exists(x) And Not LCase(Dic(x)) Like "*|" & LCase(y) & "|*" Then
            Dic(x) = Dic(x) & "|" & y & "|"
        End If
    Next Cl
    Range("A2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    i = 2
    For Each Key In Dic
        Cells(i, "A") = Split(Dic(Key), "|")(0)
        Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "C")) = Split(Key, "|")
        Cells(i, "D") = Replace(Split(Replace(Dic(Key), "||", ";"), "|")(1), ":", ";")
        i = i + 1
    Next Key
    Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to assume we are familiar with your document. This is not the case, an example: "If an exact match is found in column D..." matching with what? "...I want to sum the "G" and "H" values..." Sum them together (G + H)? "...from the duplicate..." Duplicate of what? "...merging into the original." original what?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad

Edited, does this clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are trying to copy seems overly complex and relies on objects only available on the Windows platform.  I started from scratch to meet your needs with simpler code--I hope you are able to follow it and adjust as needed.

It combines data in this sheet:

[image]

into this:

[image]

```
Sub merge_rows()
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim col As Integer
    
    Set s = ActiveSheet 'use this line to process the active sheet
    'set s = thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' use this line to process a specific sheet
    
    last_row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'find the last row with data
    
    For row = last_row To 3 Step -1
        If s.Cells(row, "D").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "D").Value Then
            ' found a match in column d
            
            ' add column G
            s.Cells(row - 1, "G").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "G").Value + s.Cells(row, "G").Value
            
            ' add column H
            s.Cells(row - 1, "H").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "H").Value + s.Cells(row, "H").Value
            
            'append all other columns if different
            For col = 1 To 6
                If Not s.Cells(row, col).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value Then
                  s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value & " " & s.Cells(row, col).Value
                End If
            Next
            
            ' now delete the duplicate row
            s.Rows(row).Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Grove Thank you for the reply, this gives me a lot to work through and expand my knowledge.

Comment: @Grove 

I switched the columns the code adds to 'F" and 'G', and it works fine for 'G' but appends instead of sums for 'F'. 

I can't see how this would cause any changes to the code, does it have something to do with how it steps -1?

Comment: @dougmackie, The "step -1" is making it move from the bottom up.  This results in slightly simpler code than working from the top down.  I expect the appending is happening because one or both of the values you are trying to add together are strings rather than numbers.  That is, while  

x = 1 + 2

puts 3 in x,

x= "1" + "2"

puts 12 in x.  There may be something similar happening with your data.

Comment: I see that you got this clarification explained in by posting another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504337/code-is-appending-when-it-should-be-adding-sum).  If this solution was helpful, you should up-vote it and mark it as the selected answser.

Comment: I've been trying to change this code you provided so that everything is the same except instead of appending it simply overwrites. I can't seem change that section without breaking it

Comment: for that, you should only need the following one line inside inside the "for col = 1 to 6" loop: s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value =  s.Cells(row, col).Value